# Objective-C: preferred way to retrieve the superclass of a Class instance

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am wondering which of the two following methods is the correct or preferred one to retrieve the superclass of a `Class` variable:

1. `Class getSuperclass(Class cls) { return [cls superclass]; }`
2. `Class getSuperclass(Class cls) { return class_getSuperclass(cls); }`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418498-class_getsuperclass?language=objc) on `class_getSuperclass()` say this:

> You should usually use NSObject‘s superclass method instead of this
> function

So, I'd go with door #1.

Comment: Because using this function should "#import <objc/runtime.h>" firstly. I'm kidding...

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is technically correct (yes, that's what the docs say), and yet it's an incorrect answer.

> [* superclass] *only* exists for objects that are subclasses of
>   NSObject.

Yes, that's most of the classes you use day to day.

However ... there are many classes you *might* encounter which are *not* NSObject subclasses.

Easy example: if you iterate over "all loaded classes" (e.g. using objc_getClassList), then many of the returned classes will *crash* your app if you use the [Class superclass] method.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable addition. In my case it worked as expected since I was only using it for specific classes which were derived from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 2):

I am positive they are absolutely identical, meaning that `NSObject`'s `superclass` is implemented via `class_getSuperclass`. I am not sure, but I'd bet a beer on it.

Comment: I wouldn't bet against you, though I think a reasonable style guide for Obj-C is not calling the runtime's C interface if there's an equivalent object message.

Comment: Agreed, and I'd go with `NSObject superclass`, as well. But I think they are both "correct", as the OP requested.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrea. I checked the other answer because it also contains a link to the documentation where they suggest to call ```[NSObject superclass]```.